# What type of edits will change a ReplicaSet and StatefulSet AGE?

Tags: go, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-statefulset, client-go

What type of edits will change a ReplicaSet and StatefulSet AGE(CreationTimeStamp)?

I'm asking this because I noticed that

1. If I change a Deployment image, a new ReplicaSet will be created.
2. The old ReplicaSet continues to exist with DESIRED set to 0.
3. If I change back to the previous container image, the 2 ReplicaSets don't change their age nor are recreated.

So, what is the best way to verify if there were recent updates to a Deployment/ReplicaSet and StatefulSet?

So far, I'm using client-go to check these resources ages:

```
func statefulsetCheck(namespace string, clientset *kubernetes.Clientset) bool {
    // get the statefulsets in the namespace
    statefulsets, err := clientset.AppsV1().StatefulSets(namespace).List(context.TODO(), metav1.ListOptions{})
    if errors.IsNotFound(err) {
        log.Fatal("\nNo statefulsets in the namespace", err)
    } else if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("\nFailed to fetch statefulsets in the namespace: ", err)
    }

    var stsNames []string
    for _, sts := range statefulsets.Items {
        stsNames = append(stsNames, sts.Name)
    }
    fmt.Printf("\nStatefulsets in the namespace: %v", stsNames)
    
    // check if the statefulsets are older than the 9 days
    for _, sts := range statefulsets.Items {
        stsAge := time.Since(sts.CreationTimestamp.Time)
        fmt.Printf("\nStatefulset %v age: %v", sts.Name, stsAge)
        if stsAge.Minutes() < 5 {
            fmt.Printf("\nStatefulset %v had recent updates. Skipping...", sts.Name)
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func replicasetCheck(namespace string, clientset *kubernetes.Clientset) bool {
    // get the replicasets in the namespace
    replicasets, err := clientset.AppsV1().ReplicaSets(namespace).List(context.TODO(), metav1.ListOptions{})
    if errors.IsNotFound(err) {
        log.Fatal("\nNo replicasets in the namespace", err)
    } else if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("\nFailed to fetch replicasets in the namespace", err)
    }
    
    var rpsNames []string
    for _, rps := range replicasets.Items {
        rpsNames = append(rpsNames, rps.Name)
    }
    fmt.Printf("\nReplicasets in the namespace: %v", rpsNames)
    
    // check if the replicasets have recent updates
    for _, rps := range replicasets.Items {
        rpsAge := time.Since(rps.CreationTimestamp.Time)
        fmt.Printf("\nReplicaset %v age: %v", rps.Name, rpsAge)
        if rpsAge.Minutes() < 5 {
            fmt.Printf("\nReplicaset %v had recent updates...", rps.Name)
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> AGE(CreationTimeStamp)

A resource's `CreationTimeStamp` (and thereby its age) is set when a resource is **created**. E.g. to change it, you must *delete* the resource and create it again.

Comment: Alright, what type of edits will make the resource be recreated, then?

Comment: No, edit, you need to **delete** the resource.